# C# TcpListener streamreader.readline is stuck

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

I have made a simple tcp listener server that i connect to from my mobile phone to control my ceiling light. But every now and then it gets stuck at a streamreader.readline from the connectiong client

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener (IPAddress.Any, 8001);
        listener.Start ();


        //--------------------------MAIN LOOP--------------------------
        while (true) 
        {

            //Recieve connection and take care of response
            Console.WriteLine ("Awaiting connection");

            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient ();
            Console.WriteLine ("Client accepted");

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (client.GetStream ());
            Console.WriteLine ("1:3");

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter (client.GetStream ());
            Console.WriteLine ("1:4");

            string fullrequests = "/no/request/value";
            Console.WriteLine ("1:5");


            fullrequests = sr.ReadLine (); <---- IT'S STUCK HERE
            Console.WriteLine ("1:6");
```

It's stuck so that "1:6" never is printed out to the screen. If I reload the connection from my phone it passes by and restarts but sticks at the same place again. If I sneak in another connection from another device in between there is a chance that it goes back to normal. Any ideas on why this is or how to get around it?

Comment: Do you send a string with a new line character(s) at the end?

Comment: that line is waiting for incoming string with "\n" at the end.

Comment: `ReadLine()` is blocking method. It will block until line will arrive (text message with `"\xD\xA"` at the end). You can try to set timeout, read asynchronously or read bytes/string.. but not the line. The easiest is probably to check before reading.

Comment: client.RecieveTimeout = 4000; Appears to have solved the problem temporarily. I now encounter the error "Read failiure" on the sr.ReadLine, but that I can get around. Thank y'all for answering. Iäll look in to the more stable solutions later, but this is good enough for now

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, you can check for `client.Available` - if there is incoming data, it will be greater than 0, and then you can read.

I built a library and NuGet package around simplifying this not too long ago; I was spending more time making sockets happy than I was making progress on apps. It might help you to look at the code for that for reference; while it's not a shining example of performance, it works very well for handling a few socket connections in an app.

https://github.com/BrandonPotter/SimpleTCP/blob/master/SimpleTCP/Server/ServerListener.cs

```
            List<byte> bytesReceived = new List<byte>();

            while (c.Available > 0 && c.Connected)
            {
                byte[] nextByte = new byte[1];
                c.Client.Receive(nextByte, 0, 1, SocketFlags.None);
                bytesReceived.AddRange(nextByte);

                if (nextByte[0] == _delimiter)
                {
                    byte[] msg = _queuedMsg.ToArray();
                    _queuedMsg.Clear();
                    _parent.NotifyDelimiterMessageRx(this, c, msg);
                } else
                {
                    _queuedMsg.AddRange(nextByte);
                }
            }
```

[NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleTCP/)

Comment: This seems great and I will look into it. 
For some reason I can't upvote this answer.